# How do I get my Score Counter to work properly?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int Score = 0;
    Scanner answerCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Question 1. Who is the leader of the Straw Hat Crew?\n");
    System.out.println("A.Zoro\n"+"B.Luffy\n"+"C.Jimbei\n"+"D.Chopper\n"+"Enter your Answer:");
            String answerOne = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerOne.equals("b")){
            System.out.println("You are Correct !\n"+ (Score+1)); 
        }
            else{System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was B.Luffy");
            }
    System.out.println("Question 2. Who was defeated in Wano?\n");
    System.out.println("A.Gecko Moria\n"+"B.Ace\n"+"C.Blackbeard\n"+"D.Kaido\n"+"Enter your Answer:");
                String answerTwo = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerTwo.equals("d")){
            System.out.println("You are Correct !"+ (Score+1)); 
        }
            else{System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was D.Kaido");
            }
    System.out.println("Question 3. Who gave Luffy  his straw hat?\n");
    System.out.println("A.Shanks\n"+"B.Nami\n"+"C.Rayleigh\n"+"D.Hawkins\n"+"Enter your Answer:");
                String answerThree = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerThree.equals("a")){
            System.out.println("You are Correct !+ (Score+1)"); 
        }
            else{System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was A.Shanks");
            }
```

I tried to make a running Score for this quiz but it does not function properly. It comes up as a string of sorts when I try to run the program. Any help here would be much appricated.

Comment: "does not function properly" is not a sufficient problem statement. Post clear details.

Answer (score 1):

2 main errors:

1. using `Score + 1` during string concatenation just print the value of Score plus one, don't increment Score value, if you want to do it inline you have to use `++Score` syntax that is equivalent to do `Score = Score + 1` **before** use score value in string concatenation. Using the most common notation `Score++` will print `Score` value before incrementation. See official [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) for details !
2. There is a typo in the last `"You are Correct !+ (Score+1)"` syntax, in this way it always print `+ (Score+1)`, do not sum anything!

that's work

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScoreCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Score = 0;
        Scanner answerCheck = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Question 1. Who is the leader of the Straw Hat Crew?\n");
        System.out.println("A.Zoro\n" + "B.Luffy\n" + "C.Jimbei\n" + "D.Chopper\n" + "Enter your Answer:");
        String answerOne = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerOne.equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("You are Correct !\n" + (++Score));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was B.Luffy");
        }
        System.out.println("Question 2. Who was defeated in Wano?\n");
        System.out.println("A.Gecko Moria\n" + "B.Ace\n" + "C.Blackbeard\n" + "D.Kaido\n" + "Enter your Answer:");
        String answerTwo = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerTwo.equals("d")) {
            System.out.println("You are Correct !" + (++Score));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was D.Kaido");
        }
        System.out.println("Question 3. Who gave Luffy  his straw hat?\n");
        System.out.println("A.Shanks\n" + "B.Nami\n" + "C.Rayleigh\n" + "D.Hawkins\n" + "Enter your Answer:");
        String answerThree = answerCheck.next();
        if (answerThree.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("You are Correct ! Score: " + (++Score));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are Incorrect, Correct answer was A.Shanks");
        }
    }
}
```